# ASP.NET - Efficiently delay code execution for single request?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, performance, sleep

I would like to delay code execution for a single request (based in IP address) efficiently without affecting the overall server performance (so `Thread.Sleep` is not an option?).

How can this be done?

(this is to annoy specific people for a certain amount of time, while still providing correct functionality when the time is over..)

Comment: perhaps relevant: [How to prevent unauthorized spidering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/449418/71059)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I wouldn't do such thing in your application layer, this is a Web server task rather than your own logic.

Instead of that, what about this IIS module?

- http://www.iis.net/download/DynamicIPRestrictions

Answer (score 0):

you can do it serving content using pageMethods and delay the ajax call with javascript:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { PageMethods.RenderContent(); }, 100000);
```

Comment: I agree, but the original question was saying: "this is to annoy specific people for a certain amount of time". Which means in my opinion that they do not require a bullet proof solution!

Comment: Anwyay, double-check your approach... serving content using PageMethods...?