# Performing wait operation in ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, performance, sleep, async-await

I would like to hook into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314664/asp-net-efficiently-delay-code-execution-for-single-request) question, however perhaps rephrase it from a different angle.

For anti fraud purposes I would like to block visitors after a certain amount of incorrect login attempts. At this point I have a manager class which wraps the actual function call to login. The manager throws an exception if a visitor is blocked and thus the actual login method is never called. So far so good.

I would now like to change the exception throwing part to a `Thread.Sleep` kind of thingy. This is not an option however because this will block other requests to the server. Is there an **easy** alternative for this scenario perhaps using some `async` wait command or perhaps using `F#`?

Current code:

```
class Manager {
    void Execute(Action action) {
        if(user.IsBlocked)
            throw new BlockedException();
        else
            action();
    }
}
```

Preferred code:

```
class Manager {
    void Execute(Action action) {
        if(user.IsBlocked)
            //Wait for xxx minutes


        action();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply store the duration of the block in the same database your storing your user credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it this way would eat resources really quickly. You don't want multiple threads on your server (possibly dozens depending on the amount of visitors and the duration of your block) busy waiting until you can finaly send your response. Besides, it will not be clear to the visitor what is happening; it will seem as if your server is just not responding (which is true).
A better way is to just keep throwing the exception and maybe handle it more gracefully. For instance using javascript to display a countdown on the client until the time you may try again.

Comment: This is the initial solution. However this does require the user to send another request to the server to login. The code isn't actually for a login scenario but for something else which is executed in a loop. The login scenario was easier to explain. However if this `wait` operation will also eat resources (something I'm trying to find out here, and yes there will be loads of visitors), then this is a no-go and the current solution will stay in place.

Comment: It depends on the time you wait, but this wait operation will almost certainly eat more resources than just processing a new request. Think about it, every request has a certain overhead (especially if your doing something complex) and that is memory you won't be able te release until the block period has passed. Add to that the benefits of the user knowing what's going on (you could even automate the sending of a new request with javascript) and you'll agree that waiting on the server is not the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a task that just delays for a period of time (helper method already available that does so - TaskEx.Delay) and await that - then you won't be tying up a thread during that time.

so "//Wait for xxx minutes" would be "await TaskEx.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(xxx))"

You can see an example here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127291/C-5-0-vNext-New-Asynchronous-Pattern

```
Console.WriteLine("Before await");
await TaskEx.Delay(1000);
Console.WriteLine("After await");
```

Comment: I understand that this doens't 'tie up' a thread. But can this potentially cause a massive load of 'awaiting' threads on the server?

Comment: An ASP.NET thread doesn't await - it is the request that awaits. The ASP.NET thread is returned to the thread pool immediately. When the delay finishes, a ASP.NET thread is taken from the thread pool and used to continue (and possibly complete) the request.